# Ansible lookup, escaping single quotes

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to run a pip and lookup command in ansible, something like:

```
      set_fact: mydate="{{lookup('pipe','date +%d %b %r %Z')}}"
```

The above command fails because I need this part +%d %b %r %Z to be in quotes. To be more precise, this is the shell command I am trying to run in ansible using lookup

`sh-4.4$ TZ=":US/Eastern" date +'%d %b %r'`

which gives output

`12 May 04:47:32 AM`

But somehow this doesnt work when I try to add it to the lookup and pipe in ansible due to wrong quote escaping I suppose ? . How do I run the shell command using ansible pipe and lookup modules with quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just write it like this and avoid the nested quotes:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        date_utc: >-
          {{ lookup('pipe', 'TZ=UTC date "+%d %b %r %Z"') }}

    - debug:
        msg:
          - "{{ date_utc }}"
```

That's using a YAML [block scalar](https://yaml-multiline.info/) operator (`>`)  for quoting.

Also note that here we're setting the `TZ` environment variable inside the `pipe` lookup, because using the `environment` key won't work in this situation.